# Wordpress remove read more from excerpt

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having an issue with the Remove_filter() .The remove filter works but not 100% , it wont remove the first **3 dots** from Read More,and it wont replace the parent excerpt.

More clearly what I am trying to do, is to remove **Read More** and change it into **[...]** .

***I want this to be done from child-theme***.

Here are the screenshot exemple [Before](https://s15.postimg.org/bu0eoctff/image.jpg) and [After](https://s10.postimg.org/cfx81msa1/image.jpg).

Parent theme functions.php code

```
    function new_excerpt_more($more) {
    global $post;
    return '… <a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . 'Read More!   &raquo;'     . '</a>';
   }
    add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

Child-theme functions.php code.

```
       function child_theme_setup() {
       // override parent theme's 'more' text for excerpts
       remove_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more' ); 

      }
     add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'child_theme_setup' );
    // Replaces the excerpt "Read More" text by a link
     function new_excerpt($more) {
     global $post;
     return '<a class="moretag" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">[...]                      </a>';
      }
      add_filter('excerpt', 'new_excerpt');
```

Comment: specify your problem clearly..

Comment: @HappyCoding ,i edited it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just need to update your code a little bit.

```
// Changing excerpt more
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
  global $post;
  remove_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more'); 
  return ' <a class="read_more" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . ' do whatever you want to update' . '</a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more','new_excerpt_more',11);
```

The default priority of a hook is 10. It is possible that the parent theme's hook gets added second, meaning both your hook and the parent hook have the same priority but the parent's came last therefore it doesn't reflects changes.

Comment: It still the same , the 3 dots still remains . and what i write there it wont change.

Comment: update the hook priority to 11.. then check the result

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to write a new function and only want it to work in a specific area, you can also try the wp_trim_words() function combined with get_the_content()

Example:

```
<?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), 60) ?>
```

What the above will do is trim the words down on whatever returns from get_the_content() to the number of words you want (in this case, 60).